# Add an escape character before comma+space in a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How do I add an escape character `"\"`  before each `", "` in a file? (that's a comma followed by a space).

P.S. Those quotes are for formatting purposes and are not presented (nor should appear in the file).

Comment: sure you dont want to add the normal escape character ( \ ) ?

Comment: @amdixon oopsie, thanks for pointing that out :) (have updated the question)

Comment: Have you tried anything with `sed` or `awk` or `ed`?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I know it is a way to go, but they are my kryptonite - i tried many times before and stopped even trying now/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this example, if it is helpful for you:

```
kent$  echo "foo,bar,blah"|sed 's/,/\\,/g'
foo\,bar\,blah
```

if you want to replace the comma, only if there is a space followed, do this:

```
kent$  echo "foo, bar, blah,skipme"|sed 's/, /\\&/g'
foo\, bar\, blah,skipme
```

Comment: Thanks! How do i add a space to that equation? (yes, i am that bad :( )

Comment: you didn't mention spaces part. how should I know where do you want to put your space? make your question complete first please.

Comment: I certainly did -- How do i add an escape character "\" before each ", " in a file? -- there is a space after a comma

Comment: In the question it's mention of `, ` (comma followed by a space—not easy to see).

Comment: @Dennis you should use code block.  and this one-liner just do replacement on `,`, if there is space followed, the space won't be touched. Have you tested the line with your data?

Comment: just need an extra spaces in the command like `.. sed 's/, /\\, /g'`

Comment: @Dennis check the updated answer, if it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**For each character**
put wanted character to escape in a class `[ ,]` (space and `,`in this case`)

```
echo 'Your, string or data' | sed 's/[, ]/\\&/g'
```

there is special rules for `]`, `-` and `\` (see RegEx class documentation for this)

**For specifing pattern**

```
echo 'Your, string or data' | sed 's/, /\\&/g'
```